# The provided '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember' for 'odata.type' is not valid for this operation

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a mysterious issue that I don't understand. I'd like to do an application that can send a Teams (Microsoft Teams) message to a specific user.

Furthermore, I can achieve this without trouble using the API (with Postman).

[image]

As you can see, I don't have any issue to do the request.

However, when I do this with my app (using Flutter) I get an error 400 with this message :

```json
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The provided '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember' for 'odata.type' is not valid for this operation., The provided '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember' for 'odata.type' is not valid for this operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-15T13:58:13",
            "request-id": "99a5b654-d137-4c4f-9473-234747b32c42",
            "client-request-id": "99a5b654-d137-4c4f-9473-234747b32c42"
        }
    }
 }
```

Obviously, my access token is exactly the same as well as permissions to achieve this request. User's IDS are also the same.

What I am doing:

**The request**

*headers*: contains the token and the responseType

```dart
    final url = Uri.https('graph.microsoft.com', "/v1.0/chats");
    final body = ChatMemberDto(
            personId: personId,
            visitedPersonId: visitedPersonId)
        .toJsonStr();

    var response = await http.post(url, headers: _headers, body: body);
```

**ChatMemberDto**
*I know, not well-designed ;)*

```dart
class ChatMemberDto {
  String personId;
  String visitedPersonId;

  ChatMemberDto({required this.personId, required this.visitedPersonId});

   String toJsonStr() {
    var data = {
      "chatType": "oneOnOne",
      "members": [
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
          "roles": ["owner"],
          "user@odata.bind":
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$personId')"
        },
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
          "roles": ["owner"],
          "user@odata.bind":
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$visitedPersonId')"
        }
      ]
    };
    return jsonEncode(data);
  }
}
```

I have followed the documentation described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I guess the issue come from my code, because I can do it with Postman. But I can’t understand why??

PS: I've tested it on Android Emulators and real Android devices

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Can you try pasting the body from the code in postman  and check if it is working. I think you need to sent the data as json from the application

Comment: I have already do this. It works with postman. Body as sent as json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake. I post here in case someone gets the same error as me.

```dart
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats'));
request.body = '''{"chatType":"oneOnOne","members":[{"@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember","roles":["owner"],"user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users(\'XX-XXX-XXXX-XXX\')"},{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember","roles":["owner"],"user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users(\'XX-XXX-XXXX-XXX\')"}]}''';
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

I've used another lib. Don't really know why it is working with this way and not with the other (see my question) ??

But anyway, this solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the conversion to string
Can you try like this and check if it is working

```
class ChatMemberDto {
  String personId;
  String visitedPersonId;

  ChatMemberDto({required this.personId, required this.visitedPersonId});

  String toJsonStr() {
    var data = {
      "chatType": "oneOnOne",
      "members": [
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
          "roles": ["owner"],
          "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users($personId)"
        },
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
          "roles": ["owner"],
          "user@odata.bind":
              "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users($visitedPersonId)"
        }
      ]
    };

    return jsonEncode(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this doesn't change anything. I still got the same error. The generated JSON Sting is valid and works with postman (the user id must be surrounded by single quotes, I have adapt it, but doesn't fix the issue)